# How do I track page visits with setcookie()?

Tags: php

thanks for taking the time to read this.

**Intro: (with some additonal info)** 
How do I check how many "visits" I get on a page. 
For the school excersize I have to do something with both setcookie() and headers(), 
however I don't know what headers() has to do with checking the amount of visits my page gets.

**Goal:** 
Being able to track the amount of visits I have on my webpage using setcookie() and headers(). 
I can take care of displaying it, I just need the technical side of it. :) 
(EDIT) A bit of extra information:

- I use MySQL to do this on my laptop locally
- I have to be able to open and close the tab (whilst keeping MySQL running) and the page counter should not go back down to 0

**Current code:** 
(It's kinda sad, I know)

```
<?php
    $visits = 1;
    setcookie(
        'count',
        $visits,
        time() + 60 * 60 * 24,
        '/'
    );
    if(isset($_COOKIE)) {
        $visits += 1;
    } else {
        exit;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Visit counter</title>
</head>
<p> Current visits: </p>
<body>
    <?php
    echo $_COOKIE['count'];
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you (again) to anyone taking their time to read and/or respond to this question.
I seriously appreciate it!

(Edit: If I need to explain more, please ask!)

Comment: Just like you, I don't see where `header()` would play a role here. However, just using cookies won't give you the number of visitors, since a cookie is only stored in the client (the browser) and is only for that visitor. You need to have some central persistent storage in the back end (database/file or similar) to store it. Basically, check if a cookie is set, if not, register a new visit in the db/file and set the cookie. Then it will only be set on the first visit and you have a central storage where you can see the total number of visitors.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think I should have clarified that I need to just do this on my own laptop for an excorsize. So I'll be using MySQL. I'll have to be able to a) close the tab and when I open it, the counter isn't back to 0 and b) when I refresh the page I'll have to see the number go up. I'm glad I'm not the only one who doesn't understand the header() bit! :D -

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67570956/edit) your question to include a proper and full explanation about the requirements. But if you only need to do it for you, then a cookie should work. Please do some proper attempts, seeing that the code you've posted doesn't even try to do half of what the requirements say. However, the `$visits` value should be numeri. You need to read the cookie on each visit, if it doesn't exist, set it to 1, otherwise increment it and store it back in the cookie.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes! I have edited the question. Thank you for the great advice. Well my previous code is so ugly I did not want to share it. I have heard that people here tend to be ruthless when it comes to noobies. On top of that now I know that it's called "reading a cookie" I did not know that before so that oughta make googling easier. 

Thank you for your great advice! :D I appriciate it sincerely.

Comment: Don't worry about ugly code. People here are more ruthless if you don't post any proper attempts. We're glad to help you sort out specific issues with your existing code, but we're not here to write code for you, nor to talk about high level solutions. New developers are absolutely welcome, but we do require that people do proper [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some serious attempts before asking here.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Hi! Thanks for the link to the research page. That's very informative, love the feedback and constructive critisism (deff spelled that wrong). I added in my previous code, which is ugly and wrong however it works up to 1! (yay). I understand, I do not want you guys to write my code. Because a) it's my job and b) I want to understand what I'm doing, so in the end I would only burdain myself. Thank you again Magnus! I appreciate it(again).

Comment: The idea of cookie could work like this...every time cookie isset increment db value by +1 and re insert or alternatively every time cookie isset increment +1 to a value in a file

Comment: @KevinGales Thank you very much, I like appreciate your input (pun intended).